# Create an accept check-box using HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html, button, imagemap

I have created an accept checkbox (like in stackoverflow.com), using jquery. I used [maphilight.js](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) plugin.

In details, I created an image map, I defined my area, and applied the plugin so that this area is highlighted on mouseover, changed color on click.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.maphilight.js"></script>

    <script>$(function() {

        $('#star,#starlink2').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $('#star').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
            data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
            $('#star').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        });
    });</script>
```

HTML side:

```
<img src="image.png" width="300" height="301" class="map" usemap="#features">
<map name="features">

<area id="star" shape="poly" coords="78,83,70,100,52,104,64,115,61,133,78,124,94,133,91,116,104,102,87,101,79,88" href="#" alt="star" class="group" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}'>

</map>
```

I am sure I can do it with another approach better that using maphighlight.js, maybe using one of the HTMLs libraries, that I dont know. The problem I cannot find the keywords to put in my searches to find the best approach.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just look at the source for SO, if you want it to be the same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve do you have print screens ?

Comment: I can think of a 100 better approaches depending on your end result. Can you give us some pics or a jsFiddle of your expected end result? I don't even really know why people use mapping anymore. I've designed complicated military layouts, doctors apps, and law enforcement apps that require all kinds of crazy things, havn't used a map in over a decade. lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH lol. Give me only one approach to create an accept button, like the green one available in SO answers, without using the maphighlight.js. I am a beginner, and I am  looking for the name of a technology to use, then I can digg myself to know how to use it. I am lacking of search engine keywords.

Comment: @musefan: good idea I will do it.

Comment: @Mehdi Karamosly: I am trying to achieve a stackoverflow-like accept button for a buddypress-based community where all backend functions are migrated to front end.The button is binded to a custom field. The admin have to accept the work done by members by clicking on the accept button. This way, the member knows that the work is validated. Thank you ba Mehdi.

Comment: Uhm, did I miss the meeting? I don't have any green buttons anywhere on my SO site load?

Comment: @SpYk3HH It means you never asked a question on SO, you only answer. Well, when you post a question, SO gives you the ability to check the right answer among all the answers. SO provides with a check-like white image which becomes green if you click it.

Comment: isn't that just an anchor element with a background set to an image sprite that changes position based on the class of the div? it's a pretty simple concept, and doesn't even need any javascript other than for the click events. commonly called a roll-over image, or... a button with states?

Comment: @KevinB I told it in my post, I feel there is a more simple approach, and the one you are suggesting is smart and simple. It will be good if you provide with an answer containg some code so that I can click on the accept button (the SO one)

Comment: I have asked questions, and that's just a checkbox on my screen, not a button, and still no greenness, lol. sounds like they would prolly just use an image sprite and change background position based on action, hover, etc...

Comment: @SpYk3HH Totally agree with you, thank you for your time.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I have edited the title of my question

Comment: Sorry to waste your time with my comments, I'm just trying to get exactly what you are trying to achieve so i can give you one of my 100's of (weaselly self proclamation voice) "Brilliant ideas!"

Comment: Just fyi, you can't "technically" style a checkbox, however, there are a TON of jQuery plugins prebuilt to give you pretty checkboxes with ease of use. [(1)](http://localpcguy.github.io/Kalypto/) [(2)](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) [(3)](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/checkbox/) [(4)](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/) just to name a few

Comment: Thank you very much @SpYk3HH, very intersting. Again, thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with an image sprite and css. I'm not going to go into what an image sprite is other than for example we have one split in half, the left half is the unaccepted image, the right half is the accepted image. You could have more states if you wish, and the sprite can be organized vertically instead if you want.

```
a.btn-accept {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff url("my-image-sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
a.btn-accept:hover, .btn-accept-accepted {
    background-position: -50px 0px;
}
```

and then with a little js toggle the the accepted class on click.

```
$(".btn-accept").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-accept-accepted");
});
```

Comment: I will implement it. This is the starting point. Thank you very much